# Does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{1+n^4x^2}$ converge uniformly?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This is a very simple question and still I have a problem with that. I want to check whether this series converges   $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{1+n^4x^2}$ where $x \in [0, \infty]$

This is an attempt to use the M-Weierstrass test for uniform convergence:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\frac{x}{1+n^4x^2} |\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\frac{x}{n^4x^2}| \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\frac{1}{n^4x}|\leq \frac{1}{|x|} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\frac{1}{n^4}|$
when $x$ is not 0, bus still fixed. For 0, It's easy to see that there's a uniform convergence. I feel that something is wrong with this use of this test. What is wrong? and What is the correct way showing the uniform convergence?

Comment: I think that's correct for $|x|\geq1$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since, for every $x$ in $\mathbb R$ and integer $n\geqslant1$,
$$
\left|\frac{x}{1+n^4x^2}\right|\leqslant\frac1{2n^2},
$$
the series is [normally convergent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_convergence) on $\mathbb R$. In particular, it is [uniformly convergent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#Definition) on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I feel dumb asking, but why is this inequality holds?

Comment: @Elimination What did you try to prove it?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that [Dini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem) is applicable here.

Comment: Should I need to show that just $a_n$ is a monotic function for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$?

Comment: $[0,\infty)$ is not compact.

Comment: @zulon The OP has a solution away from zero. The issue is on [0,1].